AndroidFragmentApplication error with libgdx 1.12.1
I would like to use libGDX with in a fragment (AndroidFragmentApplication). I am using libgdx version 1.12.1 and I have this error :
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for java.nio.ByteBuffer com.badlogic.gdx.utils.BufferUtils.newDisposableByteBuffer(int)

When I am implementing the same code in my class ApplicationAdapter() from an AndroidApplication() I don't have any problems...
For more details, I am implementing a FlappyBird game : (https://github.com/kostasdrakonakis/flappybird/tree/master)
My code with AndroidApplication
class MainActivity : AndroidApplication() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        initialize(FlappyBird(), AndroidApplicationConfiguration())
    }
}

and with FragmentActivity :
class MainActivity : FragmentActivity(), AndroidFragmentApplication.Callbacks {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val libgdxFragment= AndroidGameFragment()
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment, libgdxFragment).commit()
    }
    override fun exit() {}
}

my layout activity :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="#830ECC"
    tools:ignore="MissingClass">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="40dp"/>

</LinearLayout>

My extend class AndroidFragmentApplication
class AndroidGameFragment() : AndroidFragmentApplication() {
    private val myGdxGame = FlappyBird()

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
        val config = AndroidApplicationConfiguration()
        myGdxGame.create()
        return initializeForView(myGdxGame, config)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    }
}

Thanks in advance guys
